# Is it possible to make GlobalConfiguration.Configure asynchronous?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

The entry point to a web api project is in the `global.asax` and the boilerplate code is this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

This calls the Register method which is `static void`. During setup, I want to make various calls that use `async Task`. Is there an elegant way to do this other than wrapping every async call in `Task.Run(() => myMethod).Wait();`?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question, I think you could do something like this:

```
Task<string> getStringTask = someGetStringAsyncMethod();
Task<object> getObjectTask = someGetObjectAsyncMethod();

Task.WaitAll(new Task[] {
    getStringTask,
    getObjectTask,
});

string theString = getStringTask.Result();
object theObject = getObjectTask.Result();
```

I guess if you don't  need the results then you could call the async methods directly in the WaitAll.